# mongodb - $lookup not searchable

Tags: mongodb

So i have two collections

1. petrolStations
2. petrolData

They are linked by the petrolStations `$_id`

as I need to go a `$geoNear`

I planned on doing the following

```
[{$geoNear: {
 near: {
  type: 'Point',
  coordinates: [
   115.951869,
   -31.940377
  ]
 },
 spherical: true,
 distanceField: 'distance',
 distanceMultiplier: 0.000621371,
 maxDistance: 100000,
 includeLocs: 'location'
}}, {$sort: {
 distance: 1
}}, {$lookup: {
 from: 'petrolData',
 localField: '_id',
 foreignField: 'storeid',
 as: 'latest'
}}]
```

While technically that works - by creating a subarray. I can't workout how I search the PetrolData to only return based on the following

1. is petrolData.date field eq to today
2. is petrolData.price NOT null

Also I don't want it in a subarray if possible.

Sample data

PetrolStation

```
/** 
* Paste one or more documents here
*/
{
  "_id": ObjectId("626f47fe6220ff227b587d01"),
  "location": {
    "coordinates": [
      115.80609,
      -31.904837
    ],
    "type": "Point"
  },
  "store": "United Osborne Park",
  "address": "479 Scarborough Beach Rd, OSBORNE PARK"
}
```

petrolData Sample Data

```
/** 
* Paste one or more documents here
*/
{
  "date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1651461677000"
    }
  },
  "storeid": {
    "$oid": "626f47fe6220ff227b587d01"
  },
  "__v": 0,
  "price": 1.95,
  "typeOfFuel": "91"
}
```

Based on the answer below I created this query.

```
[{$geoNear: {
 near: {
  type: 'Point',
  coordinates: [
   115.951869,
   -31.940377
  ]
 },
 spherical: true,
 distanceField: 'distance',
 distanceMultiplier: 0.000621371,
 minDistance: 5000,
 maxDistance: 10000,
 includeLocs: 'location'
}}, {$limit: 8}, {$lookup: {
 from: 'petrolData',
 localField: '_id',
 foreignField: 'storeid',
 as: 'latest'
}}, {$sort: {
 distance: 1
}}, {$unwind: {
 path: '$latest'
}}, {$match: {
 'latest.price': {
  $exists: true,
  $ne: null
 },
 'latest.typeOfFuel': '95'
}}, {$limit: 4}]
```

However, I feel wouldn't it be faster to check if the petrol station has `latest.typeOfFuel: 95` first?

Answer (score 0):

Add an other stage to your aggregation to match the price and the date.
You might want to make the date dynamic:

```json
[
  {
    $geoNear: {
      near: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [
          115.951869,
          -31.940377
        ]
      },
      spherical: true,
      distanceField: "distance",
      distanceMultiplier: 0.000621371,
      maxDistance: 100000,
      includeLocs: "location"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      distance: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "petrolData",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "storeid",
      as: "latest"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "latest.price": {
        "$exists": true,
        "$ne": null
      },
      "latest.date": {
        $gte: ISODate("2022-05-02"),
        $lte: ISODate("2022-05-02")
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: That's what I thought too, but if you use compass you can see that each stage you add, creates a new query as such, which means it's not the best way.

I thought that you could do a $project query inside a $lookup query?

Comment: What do you mean by it's not the best way ? That's just how aggregation works.

Comment: when you do it in compass it outputs some sample data in each stage. Would that not be how in the backend MongoDB tries and run the query like that?

Comment: Yes, but this is how aggregation works. Each stage does a filter until it executes all the stages and return the final result. You should not worry about how mongoDB executes the stages that's just how it works.

Comment: @petersonCode you do start worrying when you get alerts saying you queried over 1000 documents. and no one tells you that each stage gets executed which all adds up to documents getting queried.

I have over 200 emails per day from MongoDB stating this. and that's why I am rewriting ever line of code and restructuring the database.